# Font in Word changes as soon the user types

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts

When I open a new, blank document in MS Word 2016 the font Calibri is selected. The style template is default which shows Calibri when right click => modify on it. (http://www.pcworld.com/article/2098430/how-to-set-and-keep-your-preferred-default-font-in-word.html)

However when I start typing the font changes to Times New Roman. How can I change this behaviour? Word and Outlook are affected, Powerpoint and Excel not.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might no longer be bothering you, but I have struggled with this for quite a while. I solved it by deleting the templates normal.dotx which on its own had no effect. Only after deleting the templates AND changing office's default spellcheck language as described [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365-ProPlus/Default-Office-theme-uses-Times-New-Roman-everywhere-not-Calibri/td-p/15969), Word finally stopped to fallback on Times New Roman.